# Create And Display A PDF File In Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

How to create PDF file and display as per our design.
customize PDF layout and add image and table create in PDF file.
i have send image this type i want to create pdf file .

Comment: Please tell us what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfmake) is plugin called **pdfmake**. It will help you to create pdf of images. You can customise many of things for creating pdf like page size, table, fonts etc.

Following are some of the tutorial which will help you to guide :

https://medium.com/@rakeshuce1990/ionic-how-to-create-pdf-file-with-pdfmake-step-by-step-75b25aa541a4

https://ionicacademy.com/create-pdf-files-ionic-pdfmake/

I have used it in my project to creating pdf of images and working properly, so may it will help you.